# Android: creating a linearlayout in new Activity programmatically

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a LinearLayout in another activity called MainFragment.
Inside onCreate function I'm using the line

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(MainFragment.this);
```

using `this` shows same error

error:

```
LinearLayout (andorid.content.Context) in LinearLayout cannot be applied to (com.example.name.nav_bar.MainFragment)
```

If I try the code in MainActivity it works fine.

Comment: `LinearLayout` constructor needs a `Context`, while a `Fragment` is not a subclass of `Context`, and `Activity` **is** a subclass of `Context`.

Comment: You can use either one --
`LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(getContext);`  
`LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(getActivity);`

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
```

When working with Fragments for the first time, it's important to understand how they are different from Activities. One of these ways is that an Activity is an Android `Context`, but a Fragment is not. Many things depend on having a `Context` to work with, so if you're inside a Fragment you need some way to get access to a Context. The easiest way is often to call `getActivity()` (since, again, an Activity is a Context).